# How do I enable google sheets value bubbles when highlighting portions of formulas

Tags: if-statement, formula, optional-values, bubble-popup

When I would create a formulas like =IF(A2=B2,"yes","no") and I highlighted the A2, it would create a little comment bubble above the highlighted text that gave the value that was in A2.  And if I selected A2=B2 it would give me a comment bubble stating if the selected information was TRUE or FALSE.  I had a comment bubble pop-up on me outside of the formuala circumstance and I noticed an X to close the bubble.  Since it was in my way, I clicked the bubble to get rid of it and since then, it seems none of the comment bubble are coming up as well and I can't figure out how to get them back as I use them often to troubleshoot formulas.  I tried searching for a solution, but I don't know what they are called and everything that I have tried doesn't give me the answer I'm looking for.  If anyone can let me know how to re-enable this feature, I'd greatly appreaciate it.

If searched settings and the view dropdown menu, but unable to find anything that seemed to match what I'm looking for.  Google searched gave me nothing, since I don't know what these comment bubbles are called.

Answer (score 0):

It is called "Formula help".  It can be enabled by hitting F1 key.  Found the answer when I clicked on the blue circle with a question mark to the left of my highlighted information.